# TypeScript service is undefined when calling a function from common service

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am using TypeScript with Angular JS to write a common service which will handle the POST and GET Requests to a server.

This is what the service looks like:

```
module TBApp {

    export class apiService {

        static $inject = ['$http', 'notificationService'];

        constructor(private $http, private notificationService: notificationService) {

        }

        get(url, config, success, failure) {

            return this.$http.get(url, config)

                .then(result => { this.handleResponse(result, success); }, result => { this.handleError(result, failure) });
        }

        post(url, data, success, failure) {

            return this.$http.post(url, data)

                .then(result => { this.handleResponse(result, success); }, result => { this.handleError(result, failure) });
        }

        handleResponse(result, success) {

                    this.notificationService.displaySuccess(result.data.message);

                    success(result);

        }

        handleError(result, failure) {

            if (result.status === '401') {

                this.notificationService.displayError('Authentication required.');

                //TODO: redirect to login page

            }
            else if (failure !== null) {
                failure(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so in the controller shown below I want to call `loginCompleted` on login success.

```
module TBApp {

    export class loginController extends MyApp.BaseController {

        membershipService: membershipService;
        apiService: apiService;

        static $inject = ['$scope', 'membershipService', 'apiService', '$location'];

        constructor($scope, membershipService: membershipService, apiService: apiService, private $location) {
            super($scope);

            this.scope.user = new User(null, null);

            this.membershipService = membershipService;
            this.apiService = apiService;
        }

        login() {

            // HERE: this.membershipService Is NOT NULL OR UNDEFINED

            console.log(this.membershipService);


            this.apiService.post('/api/account/authenticate', this.scope.user, this.loginCompleted, this.loginFailed);
        }

        loginCompleted(response) {

            //This method will save the logged in user to cookies

            //HERE : this.membershipService Is UNDEFINED

            this.membershipService.saveCredentials(this.scope.user);

            // redirect to home page

            this.$location.path('/');
        }

        loginFailed(response) {
            alert('login failed');
            console.log(response);
        }

    }
}
```

The function gets called everything is working except for the `this.membershipService` is undefined inside the `loginCompleted()` function.

I think this is because the `loginCompleted()` function is called from inside the `apiService`, how can I fix it? what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Dawood, you are losing context, my friend. This problem caused because you send functions (loginCompleted, loginFailed) as params, and while they executed their key word `this` linked to another object.

What you can do here - you can send that functions with binded context (it will be setted always to object which you define as first argument).

```
module TBApp {

export class loginController extends MyApp.BaseController {

    static $inject: string[] = ['$scope', 'membershipService', 'apiService', '$location'];

    constructor(
        private $scope: ng.IScope,
        private membershipService: membershipService,
        private apiService: apiService,
        private $location
    ) {

        super($scope);

        this.scope.user = new User(null, null);
    }

    login() {

        // HERE: this.membershipService Is NOT NULL OR UNDEFINED

        console.log(this.membershipService);


        this.apiService.post('/api/account/authenticate', this.scope.user, this.loginCompleted.bind(this), this.loginFailed.bind(this));
    }

    loginCompleted(response) {

        //This method will save the logged in user to cookies

        //HERE : this.membershipService Is UNDEFINED

        this.membershipService.saveCredentials(this.scope.user);

        // redirect to home page

        this.$location.path('/');
    }

    loginFailed(response) {
        alert('login failed');
        console.log(response);
    }

   }
  }
```

In this case you send functions with binded context:

```
this.loginCompleted.bind(this)
this.loginFailed.bind(this)
```

Two new functions will be created with binded context to current class.

More information about this subject: [understanding context in js](http://www.joshuakehn.com/2011/10/20/Understanding-JavaScript-Context.html)

P.S. Don't blame me I changed code style a bit. Hope my answer will help

**UPDATED code below related to comments conversation**

```
module TBApp {

export class loginController extends MyApp.BaseController {

    static $inject: string[] = ['$scope', 'membershipService', 'apiService', '$location'];

    constructor(
        private $scope: ng.IScope,
        private membershipService: membershipService,
        private apiService: apiService,
        private $location
    ) {

        super($scope);

        this.scope.user = new User(null, null);
    }

    login() {

        // HERE: this.membershipService Is NOT NULL OR UNDEFINED

        console.log(this.membershipService);


        this.apiService.post('/api/account/authenticate', this.scope.user,
            (response) => {
                this.membershipService.saveCredentials(this.scope.user);
                // redirect to home page

                this.$location.path('/');
            },
            (response) => {
                alert('login failed');
                console.log(response);
            });
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: @DawoodAwan, no issues with performance, but while you are using TypeScript, it is not recommended to use bind. Here is [article](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/bind.html) about this.

Comment: so how do I implement the above logic without using bind

Comment: @DawoodAwan, see updated block of code. We replaced one time used function in anonymus fat arrow functions which by default bind context

Comment: The cited article is biased. Arrow properties have their cons. When the method is defined on class prototype, it can be mocked/spied before class instantiation, which cannot be done for arrow properties (not a case for this particular question). The changes you've made to the original code make `login` a blackbox and hurt testability, `loginCompleted` and `loginFailed` cannot be mocked/spied anymore.

Comment: @estus, it is TypeScript, in such example those functions should be private,  private function should not be tested by definition. They should be tested end-to-end by affection other variables of SUT.

Comment: They should be tested because it improves testability, while following encapsulation paradigm strictly doesn't help anything in JS. There is `_` notation to designate private members and there are `private` and `protected` members to enforce encapsulation on TS level.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
this.apiService.post(
  '/api/account/authenticate',
  this.scope.user,
  this.loginCompleted.bind(this), this.loginFailed.bind(this)
)
```

Alternatively,

```
this.loginCompleted = this.loginCompleted.bind(this)
this.loginFailed = this.loginFailed.bind(this)
```

can be done in constructor for all callback/handler methods

Comment: what does bind do exactly?

Comment: It provides proper `this` for functions that aren't called with desired context. [See the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

Comment: Not really, it shouldn't be a concern unless the function fires 1000 times per second. It is mostly the same thing as `this.loginFailed = (...args) => this.loginFailed(...args)` (plus some extra traits).